# how to deploy node.js telegram bot on windows server

Tags: node.js, deployment, telegram-bot, windows-server, telegraf

Hello stackoverflow community

I've created a telegram bot using telegraf and node.js. the bot makes use of a database and contains sql statements (to display, insert and update data).
I have my own windows server but I have no idea how to deploy the bot on that server, I know nothing about deploying. I don't know whether I need to install any software. Please help me (please include links or steps if possible). Thank you.

Comment: Update: I decided to run the bot as a windows service instead.
step1:create .bat file 
step2: include "node index.js") in your bat file
step3: Install NSSM
step4: use NSSM to create a windows service that automatically runs and restarts itself whenever there's an error

Comment: for guidance:
https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy